# new to highchart and stuck with type datetime , data not plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to understand from this demo

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series

by changing only data  and run it , But it not working , from my understand datetime type it should be millisecond right ?

This test data is select from mysql by using command UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateTime_Field)*1000

```js
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: '[[1015174800000, 62], [1044810000000, 86], [1081011600000, 147], [1110819600000, 177], [1137344400000, 408], [1191258000000, 1612], [1221411600000, 960], [1240160400000, 960], [1291395600000, 6833], [1319043600000, 2952], [1332262800000, 3746], [1366995600000, 5612], [1417971600000, 8662], [1442250000000, 6504], [1482166800000, 15010], [1512838800000, 8168], [1526662800000, 10439], [1559581200000, 33594], [1580922000000, 22307], [1614186000000, 25955]]'
            }]
        });
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Highcharts has extensive support for time series, and will adapt
        intelligently to the input data. Click and drag in the chart to zoom in
        and inspect the data.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure looks correct, but you need to use an array instead of a string. You can use `JSON.parse` to convert.

```
  series: [{
    type: 'area',
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data: JSON.parse('[[1015174800000, 62], [1044810000000, 86], ...]')
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9vfut1k/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data